# Creating and removing layer

Tags: ios, imageview, layer

I create layer like this

```
imageView.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
imageView.layer.cornerRadius = imageView.frame.size.height / 2;
imageView.layer.borderColor = kBGColor.CGColor;
imageView.layer.borderWidth = 2.0f;
imageView.layer.rasterizationScale = [UIScreen mainScreen].scale;
imageView.layer.shouldRasterize = YES;
imageView.clipsToBounds = YES;
```

How can I remove it ?

Answer (score 1):

Remove layers same way you remove `UIView` objects

```
for (CALayer *layer in imageView.layer.sublayers) {
    [layer removeFromSuperlayer];
}
```